# 'grpcpp/grpcpp.h' file not found in Xcode using Firebase SDK

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I never had this issue but I opened Xcode and all of a sudden the SwiftUI app was not compiling throwing the error: 'grpcpp/grpcpp.h' file not found. I am using the package SDK from github (most updated version) and cant get the app to run. Anyone ran into this issue before? Thanks! Greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Found this, which might help: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1916. Here's the suggested answer from the link but feel free to read the whole thread:

> this should be an issue with misconfiguration of HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS or related settings by CocoaPods. Removing $(SRCROOT)/Pods/ from TARGETS -> Build Settings -> Header Search Paths will fix this issue.